# Run time error 5 - invalid procedure call or argument on the below VBA code to convert excel rows to individual text files with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with this macro. Every time I run it I get error Run time error 5 -  invalid procedure call or argument.

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()

Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim OutputFile As String
Dim CellValue As String
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim CurrentCol As Long
Dim CurrentCharacter As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim MyString As String
Dim fso, f

LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow

    OutputFile = "C:\Users\PARSAH\Music\ClobFiles-" & CurrentRow & ".txt"

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputFile, 8, True)
    f.WriteLine MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value
    f.Close
    
Next CurrentRow

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked fine for me.  Do you know which line is causing trouble?

Comment: "・OTD in house ,95% member: Each、Leader :ALL（メンバーは個々の実績、リーダーはチーム全体の実績）
・Service Return, vs CY20: improve 10%　member: Each、Leader :ALL（メンバーは個々の実績、リーダーはチーム全体の実績）
・ Revenue (Leader only) (各チームごとの売り上げ、リーダーのみ)
    TEK/KEI: 545,068Kyen
  　FLK:NET 459,582K yen
・Productivity ( units/ total time): improve 10%、 member: Each、Leader :ALL（生産性　昨年実績から10%改善、メンバーは個々の実績、リーダーはチーム全体の実績）
・Shipment Overdue Rate vs CY20: improve 10%  member:ALL、Leader :ALL
（売り上げ済みの案件で入荷から出荷まで稼働日が下記のターゲットに対して過ぎている超過の件の10%削減、全員がチーム全体の実績）
"
Can you try with something like this?

Comment: When I am adding this above statement in excel file and running the VBA code then I am getting error. Can you please help

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to write this with `f.WriteLine`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputFile, 8, True)
```

The syntax for `OpenTextFile` is:

```
object.OpenTextFile (filename, [ iomode, [ create, [ format ]]])
```

For your purpose, to write ***non-ASCII characters***, you need to set [format] to -1 (Unicode) as the default is 0 (ASCII characters only).

Change your line to:

```
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputFile, 8, True, -1)
```

and the code should work.

---

The above code writes in UTF-16 format. It is possible to write in UTF-8 but the process is a little different.

The following code will write a UTF-8 file:

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()    

Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim OutputFile As String
Dim CurrentRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim data As Object

LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow
    Set data = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    data.Type = 2 '(text)
    data.Charset = "utf-8"
    data.Open
    OutputFile = "C:\Users\PARSAH\Music\ClobFiles-" & CurrentRow & ".txt"
    data.WriteText MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value
    data.SaveToFile OutputFile, 2 '(write the object to a file)
    data.Close
Next CurrentRow


MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes the code worked but the file format is not UTF-8. It is UTF-16 LE.

Comment: The files need to be in UTF-8 encoding. How do I do that.

Comment: I've added a new block of code specifically for UTF-8.

Comment: @CLR While the current position of the stream is set to the beginning of the stream after a SaveToFile operation, it doesn't actually erase the contents.  So I believe the stream should first be closed, and then re-opened prior to writing new data to the stream.  Otherwise the new content may not completely overwrite the old content.

Comment: @Domenic - I thought that myself. So I tested it (admittedly, with only 2 sample lines of similar length and it seemed to work). Is there a method to clear the stream, or do we have to close and open a new one?

Comment: @CLR I didn't see any other method of doing it, other than closing and re-opening the stream.

Comment: Thanks to @Domenic for pointing out the stream needs clearing. Code altered to start a new stream each line.